# How to split the roman transcript of Sanskrit in Latex?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm writing a book with many roman transcripts of Sanskrit. Latex does not know to splite it when it appears at the end of a sentence. Like this:

[image]

Except adding hyphens one by one (too many), how can I deal with this problem? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `\hyphenation{}`? Please as usual show us a small complete code we can compile on our own computers resulting in your problem.  Then we can play with the code to help you ...

Comment: What about going the hard, probably wrong, but fruitful route? Create a `sanskrit-transliterated` _language_ in babel, include all your hyphenations and any you might also find. In your document, switch the language with `babel` methods when using sanskrit. Upload the extension to CTAN.